# MSAL and passporrt-azure-ad cannot verify token

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I have not been able to link the Azure Active Directory access control in our ReactJS application to our API, and reading through the documentation on this matter has left me with more questions than answers.

I first began by following the instructions in the AAD [Single-page app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-overview) scenario, which was straightforward and allowed me to log in to my AAD account on the web, which I mentioned previously.  That worked well.

However, when it came to configuring our NodeJS API, I was presented with two options: [A Web app that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview), and [Protected web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview).

In A Web app that calls web APIs, the registration was straightforward and led me to believe that this was the way to go, however the Code Configuration page states that only ASP, Java, and Python are supported.  I was unable to find any JavaScript examples for this scenario, so I moved on to Protected Web API.

Similarly, while I found the registration portion to be easy to follow, the Code Configuration page only listed examples in .NET, NodeJS (but only for App Functions, rather than a standalone API), and Python.  Given that the NodeJS example was close enough to a standalone API, I followed along with that code, substituting our configuration options where appropriate, seeing as it used the [passport-azure-ad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-azure-ad) package that I saw elsewhere and previously had tried to implement.  However, in both cases, every attempt to make an API call against the protected endpoint resulted in the API logging the following:

“authentication failed due to: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: cannot verify token”

Additionally, and I’m not sure how related this could be, but I noticed that when I decoded the ID Token and Access Token on the ReactJS application, the ID Token version was 2.0, but the Access Token was 1.0.  Searching through Github Issues and StackOverflow showed that others had observed this behavior as well, although I was unable to replicate their processes in order to get a v2.0 Access Token, which I suspect but am not sure is the reason for the inability for the NodeJS API to verify the token.

Oh, and I have observed the same behavior when using MSAL.js 1.3 as well as the 2.0 beta in the client, in case that helps.

Comment: What are the scopes you are using in the front-end? Make sure you ask for an access token for your API by using a scope exposed by your API. To get a v2 token, the app registration your API is using must define that it wants v2 tokens.

Comment: User.Read, as the given tutorials demonstrate.  I'm not sure what you mean by defining that it wants a v2 token.  Do you mean setting "accessTokenAcceptedVersion":2 in the Manifest?  I have done that for both the SPA and the API App Registrations (side note, should I be doing this in just one App Registration altogether or two?  I made a scope in the API App Registration ("Files.Read"), but it didn't say anything about it being a v1 or v2 in "Add a scope."

Comment: Oh yeah the scopes are not v1/v2, it's all about the version of the tokens the API accepts, which is controlled by that property you found. What you need to do is define a scope in Expose an API, and copy the full scope id to your app and use it instead of User.Read. The full scope id will include your app id URI.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  Just before we go further, I just want to make sure I'm doing the right thing: should I register just one app, or should the client and API each have separate registrations?  In either case, I used the full scope id ("api://<api_clientid>/Files.Read") in the login request scopes config for my client application, and the API still logs "cannot verify token."

Comment: Well, both approaches (one app reg/two app regs) work. If you don't expect the API to be called by other apps, it can be simpler to put it all in one app registration. Could you inspect the token you are getting at e.g. https://jwt.ms? The aud claim there should match one of the valid audiences configured for your API for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments discussion helped me discover a solution that was otherwise not made obviously clear in the MSAL examples and documentation, which was that **any MS Graph scopes in the Login Request (ex: "User.Read") would downgrade Access Tokens from v2.0 to v1.0**, which is why I was receiving v2.0 ID Tokens with v1.0 Access Tokens.

I removed all Graph scopes from the Login Request, with the API scope being the only one remaining, and as a result the following login returned a v2.0 Access Token, which was subsequently validated by the API and enabled authenticated access.